# VectorKit MapKit stack overflow crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios8, mapkit

We are seeing a strange crash in our map based iOS app that I cannot figure out. Basically as some point the following lines of code repeat over and over, more than 100 times in crash log:

```
6   VectorKit                      0x000000019050c6f8 __86-[VKMapCameraController _animateToPosition:pitch:yaw:duration:timingCurve:completion:]_block_invoke347 + 40
7   VectorKit                      0x0000000190485a30 -[VKAnimation _stopAnimation:] + 140
8   VectorKit                      0x0000000190488b20 -[VKMapCameraController setYaw:animated:] + 100
9   MapKit                         0x000000018540263c -[MKMapView snapToNorth:] + 148
```

before finally calling:

```
0   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183251e38 _CFArrayReplaceValues + 152
1   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018332876c __CFRepositionTimerInMode + 108
2   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018332876c __CFRepositionTimerInMode + 108
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183272630 CFRunLoopTimerSetNextFireDate + 580
4   MapKit                         0x00000001853e8588 -[MKMapView _didChangeRegionMidstream:] + 196
5   MapKit                         0x0000000185404e90 -[MKMapView mapLayer:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 60
```

where _CGArrayReplaceValues crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016fccbef0 error.

I'd like to point out we never directly call any of the methods in this crash report, in fact VectorKit is completely private Apple framework. The only thing we ever do in the app remotely related is call basic setRegion:animated: methods, usually after a user taps an annotation to center on said annotation. It is also worth pointing out this only happens on iOS 8. Not a single iOS 7 crash has been reported.

Here is a link for full crash report: http://crashes.to/s/f09eb96c753

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: sounds like a stack overflow due to infinite recursion, and the problem code is somewhere in the "finally" bits. Did you subclass MKMapView?

Comment: No we did not subclass MKMapView. We only use the delegate methods of the MKMapView. And there we only ever call basic setRegion methods when a user taps on an annotation, or we zoom them out if they zoom in too far. But even in the zoom in too far case, we zoom out past a threshold. I.e. if altitude is < 100, we zoom out to 115 to avoid map finicky behavior.

Comment: what happens if you change your delegate method to do nothing?

Comment: Then the app just doesn't function properly. Its tough because I cannot reproduce the crash, we just see it in Crashlytics.

Comment: maybe it's a jailbreak device?

Comment: you could also look at the assembly of the methods in question and potentially work it out that way.

Comment: Try this : Product -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Set GPU Frame Capture to Disabled

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling **NSZombieEnabled**. Once enabled, when an object reaches a retain count of 0, instead of being deallocated it'll morph itself into an **NSZombie** instance. When a zombie receives a message it will log a warning rather than crashing or behaving in an unpredictable way.

To be quite honest i'm not really sure why this is only crashing on iOS 8 and not iOS 7 but a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** signal is the result of passing an invalid pointer to a system call, so you might be dereferencing a null pointer somewhere.

If the above NSZombieEnabled doesn't uncover the issue then try using the **Static Analyzer**.

Comment: Analyzer shows no issues. Pretty sure not a memory issue. Its a stack overflow due to endless loop from Apple code, which then results in the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I just have no idea how the endless loop was entered or why it is continuing. The crash log does not record far enough back in the stack to see how it all began.